# Define number in \subsection in book class

Tags: sectioning, numbering, titlesec

I must define number be for subsubsection form :

\chapter  : 1

\section : 1.1

\subsection : 1.1.1

\subsubsection : 1.1.1.a

Can you help me define form.

Comment: Actually, I was wondering why "\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\alph{subsubsection}}" was working for me and found in documentation "\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\@alph\c@subsubsection}" didn't. Maybe it was a bit confusing, but the explanation in the comments were what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbering of `subsection`s in the `book` document class should already be in the format you require. To modify `\thesubsubsection` to show the final "number" in alphabetical rather than arabic-numeral format, you could issue the commands

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\@alph\c@subsubsection}
\makeatother
```

in the preamble of your document.

As you can probably tell from this definition, `\c@subsubsection` is a counter variable, `\@alph` instructs TeX to display the value of the counter in lowercase-alphabetical format (`a`, `b`, `c`, etc), and `\thesubsection.` instructs TeX to prepend the (already-defined) representation of the subsection counter, followed by a dot (`.`), to `\@alph\c@subsubsection`.

---

As @ThorstenDonig has pointed out in a comment, the preceding commands -- which are fairly low-level -- can be replaced with the following, higher-level command (which is especially nice at it obviates the need to use `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`):

```
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\alph{subsubsection}}
```

Comment: Why so complicated? `\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\alph{subsubsection}}` doesn't need `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

Comment: I concur with Thorsten: the user level command `\alph` is there just for this purpose.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig - Because `\alph{<counter>}` is defined in terms of `\@alph` and `\c@<counter>` and because I like using low-level commands...

Comment: Low level commands are for the advanced user. For beginners they are only confusing. And I don't think that the "normal" user is interested in low level commands.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig - Feel free to downvote my answer.